# ¿Cómo crear un script que haga distintas cosas según los parámetros que reciba?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio sobre creación de usuarios en shell script, cuyo enunciado es:

El script puede recibir hasta dos parámetros, a continuación se describen los casos a contemplar según se introduzcan 0, 1 ó 2 parámetros:

- 0 parámetros:

  El script mostrará una lista SÓLO con el login de todos los usuarios existentes en el sistema.
- 1 parámetro:

  - `-h`: Mostrará la sintaxis correcta del script, es decir la ayuda del mismo.
  - nombre_de_usuario:

    Creará el usuario con el login pasado, pero preguntará la shell, la contraseña, el directorio home, el nombre completo, la dirección de correo electrónico y el número de telefóno, creando el usuario con esos datos.
- 2 parámetros:

  - `-l nombre_de_usuario1,nombre_de_usuario2,...`:

    Hará lo mismo que en el caso de que se le pase el login de un usuario pero para cada uno de los usuarios separados por comas.

    B) En el caso de que se llame al script de forma incorrecta devolverá un error indicando que se puede llamar al script con el parámetro -h para recibir ayuda.

    C) El script solo podrá ser ejecutado por el root.

Este es el código que tengo ahora mismo:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $@ = 0 ];then
    echo $(users)
    echo $(who)
elif [ $@ = 1 ];then
    if [ $1 = "-h" ];then
        echo "Tienes que escribir el nombre del script y un nombre de  usuario o si pones mas de un usuario, tienes que separarlos por coma."
 else
    $(adduser -p -d -c $1) 
fi
elif [ $@ = 2 ]; then
    for usuario in $@;
    do
    $(adduser -p -d -c $usuario)
    done
else
   echo "Tienes que introducir el nombre del script y un nombre de usuario sino dará ERROR"
fi
```

Lo único que no me funciona es el crear el usuario con `adduser`, que no sé cómo tengo que introducirlo en la consola como parametros para que funcione tal y como pide el ejercicio.

Comment: Te he editado un poco el texto para que tenga correcto formato, pero no se por que hay puntos "b)" y "c)" sin haber "a)". puedes editarlo ?  Tambien recuerda leer [ask] y [mcve] para proveer de más informacion que pueda faltar. Un saludo

Comment: Sería bueno que plantearas dudas específicas. Así como lo planteas es más un _¿podéis revisar qué falla aquí?_. Céntrate en algún punto concreto que no funcione, dale a [edit] y pregunta eso.

Comment: AH ! Que tienes dos usuarios por error.. Mira esta publicacion de meta: [Vincular a mi cuenta de usuario una pregunta que hice como invitado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3430/15855)

Comment: en el caso de dos parametros, estas ejecutando el for con $@, y eso es el numero de parametros. Probablemente tengas que hacerlo con $2 (comprobando primero que $1 sea igual a -l, que es un requisito de tu enunciado) ademas, $2 tiene los usuarios separados por comas, por lo que tendras que ver como separarlos antes para meterlo en el for...

Comment: @Jakala no, `$@` no tiene el número de parámetros. Mira mi respuseta

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razon. Me he liado al interpretar $@.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error de base en el script, que es el de cómo se cuenta el número de parámetros: **`$#` nos dice cuántos parámetros recibe un script.** No `$@`, como hacías, que contiene un array con ellos.

Luego se trata de ir haciendo comparaciones de enteros: si quieres ver si hay dos parámetros, di `[ "$#" -eq 2 ];`, pues la comparación con `=` hará una comparación de cadenas.

En el caso de recibir el parámetro `-l` luego tienes una lista de nombres de usuario separados por coma. Esa información debes extraerla y por ejemplo puedes hacerlo con:

```
for usuario in ${2//,/ }
do
    # cosas con "$usuario"
done
```

Básicament, esto coge la variable `$2` y sustituye la coma por un espacio, para que luego el `for` los recoja uno a uno.

Con todo, la estructura final debería ser algo así como:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ];then

    # El script mostrará una lista SÓLO con el 
    # login de todos los usuarios existentes en el sistema.

elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ];then
    if [ $1 = "-h" ];then

        # mensaje de ayuda

    else

        # añade usuario "$1"

    fi

elif [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then

    if [ "$1" = "-l" ]; then
        for usuario in ${2//,/ }
        do

            # añade usuario "$usuario"

        done
    fi
else
   # mensaje de error
fi
```

Revisa también cómo haces `adduser`. Actualmente das parámetros inválidos, por lo que deberás corregirlos.

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$@` te arroja los argumentos y en tu caso te interesa el número de argumentos, así que hay que utilizar `$#` en su lugar.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function _usage {
  echo "
Sintaxis:
  $(basename $0)
  $(basename $0) [-l usaurio|usuario1,usuario2,...]

Descripción:
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
  Quos quia autem impedit necessitatibus ex saepe porro aspernatur id, 
  culpa veritatis non fuga. Impedit placeat, in rem neque explicabo veniam consequuntur!

Parametros:
  -l nombre_de_usuario     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Outputs:
  Lista los usuarios existentes en el sistema operativo.
  ....
"
}

##############
# Función _args
# -----------------
# Descripción:
#   Lorem ipsum...
#
# Argumentos:
#   $1 - Command-line arguments
function _args {
  typeset argc="$#"       # Argumentos
  typeset marg=2          # Maximo número de argumentos
  typeset mirg=0          # Mínimo número de argumentos (Opcional)

  if [[ $argc > $marg || $argc < $mirg ]]; then
    echo "No tiene los argumentos requeridos"
    exit 1 
  fi

  while getopts ":l:" OPT; do
    case $OPT in
      l) _createUser $OPTARG;;
      ?) _usage;;
    esac
  done
}

##############
# Función _createUser
# -----------------
# Descripción:
#   Lorem ipsum...
#
# Argumentos:
#   $1 - Lista de usuarios delimitada por coma.
function _createUser {
  typeset usuarios="$1"

  IFS=","
  for usuario in ${usuarios}; do
    echo "Creando usuario: \"${usuario}\"."
    #adduser -p -d -c $usuario
  done

  exit 0
}

_args $@

# Si no se envía ningún parametro al script ejecuta las siguientes lineas
grep -w home /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1 #Listar usuarios

exit 0
```

Este script necesita del `-l` para crear uno o más usuarios y si no mandas ningún parametro reliza la impresión de usuarios existentes.

Sería buena idea que añadas una función que verifique la ejecución del comando `useradd` haciendo uso de la variable `$?`.

Enlaces:

- [Variables especiales](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm)
- [getopts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/getopts.htm)