# Adduser en Shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

tengo que crear un script que pueda recibir hasta dos parámetros:

En el caso de que reciba 0 parámetros el script tiene que mostrar el login de todos los usuarios del sistema.

En el caso de que reciba 1 parámetro si el parámetro 1 es "-h" que muestre una ayuda o texto y si el parámetro 1 es un nombre por ejemplo "Antonio" crea dicho usuario preguntando la contraseña que va a querer, nombre,dirección, correo y numero de teléfono, creando el usuario con esos datos.

Si recibe 2 parámetros:

Si recibe el formato "-l Antonio, Paco hará lo mismo que el caso anterior pero creando los usuarios introducidos, separados por coma.

Si se llama al script de forma incorrecta debe devolver un error.

De momento he conseguido mas o menos la estructura del script pero solo me da un fallo tras otro y no consigo acabarlo... A ver si alguien que este mas puesto sobre ShellScripts me puede ayudar a acabarlo , porque no encuentro la forma por mas que edito el código.

Os dejo lo que llevo de código aquí:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# = 0 ];then
      echo $(users)
      echo $(who)
elif [ $# = 1 ];then
     if [ $1 = "-h" ];then
     echo "Tienes que escribir el nombre del script y un nombre de usuario o 
si pones mas de un usuario, tienes que separarlos por coma."
     else
        $(adduser -d -c $1) #no me acuerdo de como era la sintaxis exacta del 
adduser para preguntar por la contraseña
      fi
elif [ $# = 2 ]; then
    if [ $1 = '-l' ] then;
       for x in (echo $2 | cut -d ',' -f1) then
        usuario = echo $2 | cut -d ',' -f1
        $(adduser -d -c $1)
       done
    fi
else
    echo "Usa -h para más información"
fi
```

Comment: Parece que más de una persona tiene la misma tarea, habéis hecho la misma pregunta con unos días de diferencia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Fijate en la manera en la que ejecutas un comando o programa.

```
    echo $(users) 
    # Ejecutas el programa echo que imprime en la stdout del script 
    # la stdout de la ejecución del programa users.
    users
    # Ejecuta directamente el programa users y muestra la stdout directamente.

    $(adduser -d -c $1)
    # Ejecutas adduser en otro ambito y supongo que el script intentará
    # ejecutar su stdout cuando finalice interpretandolo como si fuera el nombre
    # de un programa.
    adduser -d -c $1
    # Ejecuta directamente adduser
```

2 Condiciones if, revisa la situación del **;**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [ "foo" = "foo" ]; then
        echo expression evaluated as true
    fi
```

3 Bucle for, revisa la sintaxis

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in $( ls ); do
        echo item: $i
    done
```

4 Revisa como asignas el stdout de un comando a una variable, importante los espacios

```
    var=$(comando)
```

5 Fijate si los usuarios con la opcion **-l** estan separados de la forma `Antonio, Paco`, como un string delimitado por comillas `"Antonio, Paco"` o `Antonio,Paco` ya que el espacio es tomado como delimitador [Internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) a la hora de establecer el número de parametros.

6 Date cuenta que `echo $2 | cut -d ',' -f1` únicamente imprime el primer campo delimitado por una coma, como indicas con `-f1`.

7 Te muestro por si te es útil que este bucle imprime linea a linea las letras de un string de letras separadas por espacio o cualquier otro caracter si se indica en la variable $IFS

```
    for x in $(echo "a b c d");do
        echo $x
    done
```

8 Para añadir un usuario con `adduser` [https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/adduser](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/adduser/adduser.8.en.html)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario B.Pato ,se que tengo muchos fallos de sintaxis porque soy bastante nuevo y entiendo mas o menos tus explicaciones pero podrías corregir mi ejercicio para verlo mas claro?, la verdad es que no logro ver del todo como tengo que aplicarlo a dicho ejercicio. Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Te he indicado los fallos que he visto, te toca a ti corregir tu código, probarlo y si siguiera fallando buscar el motivo y si no lo encuentras volver a preguntar por ayuda. Si me he explicado mal en algún punto di donde y puedo intentar explicarlo mejor.

Comment: @ShJod nótese que esta pregunta ya se realizó hace unos días: [¿Cómo crear un script que haga distintas cosas según los parámetros que reciba?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/163517/83), no sé si tú mismo con otra cuenta o bien otra persona